# In graph theory, what is the vertex that is being pointed to called? What is the vertex that is doing the pointing called?

Tags: graph, directed-graph

Suppose we have a **directed** graph in which vertex A points to vertex B (i.e., A->B). Just to clarify: vertex A has in-degree of 0 and out-degree of 1 while vertex B has in-degree of 1 and out-degree of 0.

Is there a special word to describe vertex A (the vertex that is doing the pointing), and is there also a special word to describe vertex B (the vertex that is being pointed)? Knowing this will help me comment my code cleanly.

Edit: I am not looking for the word that describes a vertex with zero in-degree or zero out-degree. Here is a more refined example: suppose if vertex A points to vertex B which then points to vertex C (i.e., A->B->C). Certainly, vertex B has neither an in-degree of 0 or out-degree of 0. However, in the scope of vertices A and B—meaning if we ignore vertex C—what is vertex A, and what is vertex B? What are the two words that describes vertices A and B's relationship?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the terms "head" (the vertex being pointed at) and "tail" (the vertex doing the pointing).  See [basic terminology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph#Basic_terminology) on Wikipedia's page about directed graphs.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't see this earlier when I glanced over the Indegree and outdegree section.